# Не работают формы на английской версии сайта, в чем проблема? (formit и ajaxform)

Tags: modx, formit

подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема? Вот есть русская версия сайта *balt-montage.ru/*, а есть английская версия *balt-montage.ru/en/*, на русской версии обе формы работают как надо, но на английской версии сообщения не приходят (но выходит уведомление что письмо отправлено), хотя сделано все как в русской, скидываю весь код связанный с английской версией формы, может чем подскажите, вот одна из форм:

Форма отправки через `formit` и `ajaxform`:

```
<div id="ask-question" class="fancybox-hidden">
    {if $_modx->context.key == 'en'}
    {var $question_formit_form = '@FILE chunks/callback/question/en/form.tpl'}
    {var $question_formit_mail = '@FILE chunks/callback/question/en/mail.tpl'}
    {var $question_formit_error = 'Please fill in all required fields'}
    {var $question_formit_success = 'Message sent successfully'}
    {else}
    {var $question_formit_form = '@FILE chunks/callback/question/ru/form.tpl'}
    {var $question_formit_mail = '@FILE chunks/callback/question/ru/mail.tpl'}
    {var $question_formit_error = 'Пожалуйста, заполните все требуемые поля'}
    {var $question_formit_success = 'Сообщение успешно отправлено'}
    {/if}
    {$_modx->runSnippet('!AjaxForm', [
    'snippet' => 'FormIt',
    'emailSubject' => 'Вопрос с сайта BALT MONTAGE',
    'emailTo' => $_modx->config.contacts_mail,
    'emailFrom' => $_modx->config.contacts_mail,
    'hooks' => 'recaptchav2,FormItSaveForm,email',
    'form' => $question_formit_form,
    'emailTpl' => $question_formit_mail,
    'validate' => 'name,email:required,phone:required,comment:required,g-recaptcha-response:required',
    'validationErrorMessage' => $question_formit_error,
    'successMessage' => $question_formit_success,
    'frontend_css' => ''
    ])}

</div>
```

Сама собственно форма:

```
<div class="inner-content">
  <h1>Ask your question</h1>
  <p>Leave accurate information so that our manager can send you the answer or call on the phone!</p>
  <p><span style="color:#900;"></span></p>

  <form class="b-form big-inputs" id="callback-form" method="post" action="">
    <label for="name">Your name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name"  class="grid_3" value="{$_pls['fi.name']}">

    <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" class="grid_3" value="{$_pls['fi.email']}">

    <label for="subject">Your phone</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="grid_3" value="{$_pls['fi.phone']}">

    <textarea name="comment" class="grid_6" cols="50" rows="10">{$_pls['fi.comment']}</textarea>

    <button class="btn-pink-bigger btn-pink-icon btn-margin" name="submit" type="submit">Send message</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Подскажите, как реализована локализация? Через контексты? Для русской - web, для английской - en ?